# Run R Script in Batch File

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd

So I've written an R Script that opens up the CMD do notify you when a certain condition is met:

> system('CMD /C "ECHO Condition Met"',
>            invisible=FALSE, wait=FALSE)

I am trying to automate it using a batch file with the following code

> start "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH 
>            C:\Users\User\Documents\filename.R

When I run the R file by itself, the CMD prompt saying that the condition is met pops up just fine. However, when I run the batch file, the CMD prompt saying that the condition is met no longer pops up. Instead, a blank CMD pops up. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `start` command uses the first pair of quotes as the window title

**As stated by `start /?`:**

> START ["title"] [/D path]
> "title"     Title to display in window title bar.

To overcome this, simply add quotation marks to the `start` command

**Updated Script:**

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH 
C:\Users\User\Documents\filename.R
```

Comment: I tried this, and the CMD for the R Script is still blank. The CMD for the batch file turned blank, although that's not what I'm looking for.